# How to calculate the width of screen? I want circular button size is depending on the screen resolution

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created one circular button in center of the screen and I want that button size is depending on the **screen resolution**. (I didn't have 10 reputation otherwise I post the screenshot for this)

If I set that match parent in width that makes oval (I want complete circle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `DisplayMetrics` you can get the width and height of an screen.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Comment: and how to use this width and height in xml i.e. android:layout_width="?"

Comment: you will have to assign it programmatically to the button